# How can I retrieve current X-value in gRaphael linechart hoverColumn function?

Tags: javascript, linechart, vml, graphael

Below I've posted some code and comments for making a simple gRaphael linechart with tag hovereffects (the included script files can be found at http://raphaeljs.com and http://g.raphaeljs.com). The code works as it should (and can thus be a good example for others starting out with gRaphael linecharts), but I have a question/request regarding the text argument of the tag function:

As is, the tags will display the Y values for each point (this.values[i]) at the current column, but I would like to have both the X values and the Y values displayed (X, Y). I'm sure it's pretty simple, but so far I've not been able to figure out how to do it. Adding the comma and a space is no problem, that's just `', ' + this.values[i]`, but I can't figure out how to address the X values. `this.attr("x")` is the closest I've come so far, but that's the X coordinate on the paper, not the X value on the chart's X axis ;-)

Can anyone help me out please?

```
// make tags at every point on the current column
for (var i = 0; i < this.y.length; i++) {
  this.tags.push(
  // make tag (x, y, text, degree, radius)
paper.tag(this.x, this.y[i], this.values[i], 0, 4).insertBefore(this).attr([{ fill: "#ffffff" }, { fill: this.symbols[i].attr("fill") }])
);
```

---

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="g.raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="g.line-min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">

function graphael() {

  var paper = Raphael("paper");

  var chartwidth = 800;
  var chartheight = 300;
  var charttopleftx = 20;
  var charttoplefty = 0;

  // The chart
  var linechart = paper.linechart(charttopleftx, charttoplefty, chartwidth, chartheight,

    // The X-coordinate sets
    [
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    ],

    // The Y-coordinate sets
    [
    [500, 550, 540, 510, 600, 570],
    [500, 525, 400, 450, 390, 490],
    [500, 425, 500, 430, 650, 425]
    ],

    // Chart config
    { axis: "0 0 1 1", symbol: "circle", smooth: false, axisxstep: 5 });

    // The dots
    linechart.symbols.attr({ r: 4 });

    // The tags
    linechart.hoverColumn(

      // show
      function onmousein() {

        this.tags = paper.set(); // creates a set of tags (to be able to hide them all in one operation)

        // make tags at every point on the current column
        for (var i = 0; i < this.y.length; i++) {
          this.tags.push(
            // make tag (x, y, text, degree, radius)
            paper.tag(this.x, this.y[i], this.values[i], 0, 4).insertBefore(this).attr([{ fill: "#ffffff" }, { fill: this.symbols[i].attr("fill") }])
          );
        }

      }

      ,

      // hide
      function onmouseout() {
        this.tags.hide();
      }

    );

}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="graphael()">

<div id='paper' style='width:900;height:320;'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want the coordinates of the dots on the line chart? If yes, I can post a solution.

Comment: @Neha Choudhary Yes, I want both the X and the Y coordinate of the current dot (column) to be displayed in a tag when hoovering the line chart. My code above displays only the Y coordinate (this.values[i]). Thanks

Comment: Did you try something like `linechart.symbols.cx` and `linechart.symbols.cy`?

Comment: @Neha Choudhary I've tried now, but neither of those did work. The tag just shows undefined. This is by the way not that important to me anymore, so don't spend much time figuring this out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to listing object in chrome (CTRL+SHIFT+I->Console). For example - get cy and y for every label in piechart legend.

```
var pieChart = paper.piechart(w, h, rad, values, {legend: legend, legendpos: "south", minPercent: 0.1, legendothers: "Others"});

for( var i = 0; i < pieChart.labels.length; i++ ) {
 var CY=pieChart.labels[i][0][0].cy.animVal.value;
 var Y=pieChart.labels[i][1][0].y.animVal[0].value;
}
```